# How did Mach's view on spacetime differ from Einstein's?

Tags: physics, relativity-theory, einstein, physicists

We can read in Wikipedia:

> Mach's principle, in cosmology, hypothesis that the inertial forces experienced by a body in nonuniform motion are determined by the quantity and distribution of matter in the universe. It was so called by Albert Einstein after the 19th-century Austrian physicist and philosopher Ernst Mach.

Does this lay at the center of his view on spacetime? Einstein basically says the same in his equivalence principle. Is the main difference that Mach saw spacetime being Newtonian while Einstein used it to formulate GR from SR?